# Using MySQL replication (Master/Slave) with MyBatis

Tags: java, mysql, ibatis, database-replication, mybatis

I am just wondering how I can use a Master/Slave MySQL replication database with MyBatis. JDBC offers a `com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver` (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-replication-connection.html)), but I couldn't find out where I can use similar things including all the nice properties I can configure (*roundRobinLoadBalance*, *autoReconnect*,...) in MyBatis.

Currently I have configured my none-replicated database in MyBatis like this:

```
<environments default="development">
    <environment id="development">
        <transactionManager type="JDBC" />
        <dataSource type="POOLED">
            <property name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database" />
            <property name="username" value="root" />
            <property name="password" value="" />
        </dataSource>
    </environment>
    <environment id="production">
        <transactionManager type="JDBC" />
        <dataSource type="POOLED">
            <property name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://xxx:3306/database" />
            <property name="username" value="production" />
            <property name="password" value="" />
        </dataSource>
    </environment>
</environments>
```

Has anyone a a hint for me?

Thanks for your help.

Daniel

Comment: have you tried using the `ReplicationDriver` in `<property name="driver">` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANOTHER POSSIBLE ANSWER

If you notice, the properties you're setting in the xml for the driver are also common properties set and passed to jdbc.  So, I wouldn't be surprised if MyBatis was just taking them and passing them right into the driver.  So maybe try this:

```
<environments default="development">
    <environment id="development">
        <transactionManager type="JDBC" />
        <dataSource type="POOLED">
            <!-- Just use ReplicationDriver -->
            <property name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver" />
            <property name="url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database" />
            <property name="autoReconnect" value="true" />
            <property name="roundRobinLoadBalance" value="true" />
            <property name="username" value="root" />
            <property name="password" value="" />
        </dataSource>
    </environment>
    <environment id="production">
        <transactionManager type="JDBC" />
        <dataSource type="POOLED">
            <!-- Just use ReplicationDriver -->
            <property name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver" />
            <property name="url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://xxx:3306/database" />
            <property name="autoReconnect" value="true" />
            <property name="roundRobinLoadBalance" value="true" />
            <property name="username" value="production" />
            <property name="password" value="" />
        </dataSource>
    </environment>
</environments>
```

Comment: As URL I also picked a valid replication URL and it worked. E.g. `jdbc:mysql:replication://master,slave1,slave2/database`

Comment: Awesome.  I'm glad it worked.  Is that the specific url you used?  If it is I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Yes, with master and slave1/slave2 replaced with my URLs. And I needed to remove `<property name="autoReconnect" value="true" />` and
`<property name="roundRobinLoadBalance" value="true" />` because they couldn't been found. But I will try how to configure all the stuff properly.