# spring Ibatis Mysql ReplicationDriver

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, ibatis, master-slave

i had use the spring3.1 ibatis2.x and mysql5.5. 
then i wanna use the replication driver .

my code is:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql:replication://192.168.1.160:3306/test,192.168.1.160:3306/test" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
.....
```

then：

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: 
Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Must specify at least one slave host to connect to for master/slave replication load-balancing functionality)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:224)
at $Proxy50.getMetaData(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:285)
... 50 more

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Must specify at least one slave host to connect to for master/slave replication load-balancing functionality
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:910)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringReplicationDriver.connect(NonRegisteringReplicationDriver.java:107)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
```

so how to make the ibatis to support replication

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834046/using-mysql-replication-master-slave-with-mybatis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql:replication://192.168.1.160:3306,192.168.1.160:3306/test" />
```

The format is : master,slave1,slave2

Don't why you taking same server for load balancing.